# "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" in ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, sympy

Hi I'm learning linear algebra with python with an Edx course. (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ULAFF/notebooks/tree/may-14-2014/).

On "02.4.2.10 Practice with matrix-vector multiplication" with the first box, the code is:

```
import generate_problems as gp
print("What is the result of the matrix vector product below?")

p = gp.Problem()

p.new_problem()
generate_problems is a module that the professor at Edx created. However, I got an error importing sympy.
```

While I was trying to execute the code above, I got the error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-79d56e0988cb> in <module>()
      2 print("What is the result of the matrix vector product below?")
      3 
----> 4 p = gp.Problem()
      5 
      6 p.new_problem()

/Users/user/Desktop/Course/Python/ipython/notebooks-master/generate_problems.pyc in __init__(self)
     14                 tag = ''
     15 
---> 16                 A = self.random_integer_matrix( m, n )
     17                 x = self.random_integer_matrix( n, 1 )
     18 

/Users/user/Desktop/Course/Python/ipython/notebooks-master/generate_problems.pyc in random_integer_matrix(self, m, n)
     26 
     27         def random_integer_matrix( self, m, n ):
---> 28                 A = zeros( (m, n) )
     29 
     30                 for i in range( m ):

/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/dense.pyc in zeros(r, c, cls)
   1227     if cls is None:
   1228         from .dense import Matrix as cls
-> 1229     return cls.zeros(r, c)
   1230 
   1231 

/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/matrices/dense.pyc in zeros(cls, r, c)
    511         """Return an r x c matrix of zeros, square if c is omitted."""
    512         c = r if c is None else c
--> 513         r = as_int(r)
    514         c = as_int(c)
    515         return cls._new(r, c, [cls._sympify(0)]*r*c)

/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/compatibility.pyc in as_int(n)
    387             raise TypeError
    388     except TypeError:
--> 389         raise ValueError('%s is not an integer' % n)
    390     return result
    391 

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I seems like too few %s for compatibility.py? I use Anaconda on Mac OSX Yosemite. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the course code does not support the latest version of SymPy, which has made an API change (`zeros()` now works like `zeros(r, c)` instead of `zeros((r, c))` as it is in `generate_problems.py`). You may be able to fix it by editing the code in `/Users/user/Desktop/Course/Python/ipython/notebooks-master/generate_problems.py`.